# Round to a certain decimal place

Tags: c#, rounding

I am calculating the average of some values. Everything works fine. 
What I want to do is to round the double to the 2nd decimal place.

e.g.

I would have 0.833333333333333333 displayed as
0.83

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Do you want to get a double or a string?

Answer (score 9):

Round the `double` itself like:

```
Math.Round(0.83333, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

(You should define MidpointRounding.AwayAwayFromZero to get the correct results. Default this function uses bankers rounding. read more about bankers rounding: http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm so you can see why this won't give you the right results)

Or just the display value for two decimals:

```
myDouble.ToString("F");
```

Or for any decimals determined by the number of `#`

```
myDouble.ToString("#.##")
```

Comment: The default value is MidPointRounding.ToEven. And this confirms with IEEE standard. Hence it should be left alone i.e. default value.

Comment: @MilindThakkar it depends on the application - I have seen a company that has a self billing system that needs to have different rounding schemes for different suppliers. Either rounding method *could* be correct, but that is for Duncan to know, and choose.

Comment: it's not about *display* value, and will fail on 0.857, will return 0.86 and *not* 0.85 as requested by OP:

Comment: @Tigran it'll indeed give 0.86 if the input is 0.857. But it isn't asked for to give 0.85 by this input. His example shows 0.8333 which doesn't say it has to cut off or round.

Answer (score 1):

You say *displays as* - so that would be:

```
var d = value.ToString("f2");
```

See [Standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

If you actually want to adjust the value down to 2dp then you can do what @middelpat has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Math.Round(decimal d,int decimals);
```

as

```
Math.Round(0.833333333,2);
```

This will give you the result `0.83`.

Comment: This won't always be correct. Take a look at banker's rounding: xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm You should specify the 3rd parameter MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero

Comment: @middelpat: The standard way is to .ToEven which is true as per IEEE standard. It is not good reason to down-vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, just added a comment. The downvote was someone else.

Comment: @middelpat - yes someone has come to this thread and downvoted many valid answers...

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 0.833333333333333333;
Math.Round(d, 2).ToString();
```

Comment: This won't always be correct. Take a look at banker's rounding: http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm You should specify the 3rd parameter MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero

Comment: @middelpat: The standard way is to .ToEven which is true as per IEEE standard. It is not good reason to down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
decimalVar = 0.833333333333333333;
decimalVar.ToString ("#.##");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see  `0.85781..` as `0.85`, the easiest way is to multiply by `100`, cast to `int` and divide by `100`.

```
int val = (int)(0.833333333333333333 * 100); 
var result = val /100;
```

It should produce the result you're looking for.